# jQuery and other libraries

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am having this issue with jQuery and have no idea how to solve it .... can anyone help or provide some assistance!?

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/IMM-Glossary/JavaScripts/prototype.js :: anonymous :: line 1081"  data: no]
>   Source: http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/IMM-Glossary/JavaScripts/prototype.js

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the response :) Problem is that I read the http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries - and i use "jQuery" now ? So not sure why its occurring?

P.S - About code - I don't even use my own code. I just use this plugin and jquery - and it throws error ?

Comment: maybe the plugin is using $? try change it there also.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061397/jquery-noconflict-issue , using jQuery.noConflict() should solve it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your error points to a prototype script, not jQuery.
2. You haven't posted any code.
3. [Google search.](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate+error)

Answer (score 0):

First, from the error message, it seems the problem is with the Prototype js library instead on the jQuery library.

Second, the form of the error code (0x80070057) indicates that it's a problem with a COM component.

I'm guessing that you passed an jQuery selector to Prototype -- both use $() -- and prototype doesn't know how to evaluate it.   (Prototype passes it to the nsIDOMXPathEvaluator component -- I'm gonna guess that is the "Netscape Xpath Evaluater"-- which balks at the bad XPath format)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$.noConflict()` - [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)