# JQuery Conflict with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery

Previously I have implemented some jquery in my website such as calculations etc. but when installed twitter bootstap, the previous jquery is not working

Answer (score 1):

In case of jquery conflict use the below code at above:

```
var jObj = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And use the `jObj`.

Reference: [jQuery & Prototype Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict/136502#136502)

And also [Jquery and Other Libraries Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790912/jquery-and-other-libraries-error/790977#790977)

Answer (score 0):

Different libraries of conflict with each other to ensure they work seperatly without any conflict:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Now `jQuery` is representing jQuery and all of your code should work.

For jquery code, user jQuery keyword instead of `$` and bootstrap will work with `$`.

Comment: I have done this but now my twitter bootstrap tab is not working